Taking the first n elements from list, which match a condition
I have a list, and want to know those first n elements of the list, which match a certain condition. Of course I don't want to apply my condition to all list elements, but stop the iteration as soon as I have collected my n elements.
I couldn't find a way to do it with a comprehension, so in the end, I ruled out my own solution. U.first_matches(li, n, pred) returns the first n elements from li matching the predicate pred:
defmodule U do
  def first_matches([], _n, _pred) do
    []
  end
  def first_matches(_list, 0, _pred) do
    []
  end
  def first_matches(list, n, pred) do
    first_el = Kernel.hd(list)
    if pred.(first_el) do
      [first_el|U.first_matches(Kernel.tl(list), n-1, pred)]
    else
      U.first_matches(Kernel.tl(list), n, pred)
    end
  end
end

As far I have tested it, this seems to work, but I can't believe that I need to write my own recursive function to implement such a commonplace pattern. Isn't there anything in the Elixir library, which would make my implementation simpler?

There are two modules for operating on list-like things.  Enum generally returns a list, but Stream returns a lazily-evaluated stream of results.  If you use principally the Stream functions, then you meet your requirement to not evaluate the condition more times than is necessary.
For example, say you have the integers from 1 to 100, and you want to find the first 10 even ones.  You'd do that by taking your input list, filtering on the even items, taking the first 10 items from the stream, and then materializing the result to a list.
require Integer
1..100 |>
  Stream.filter(&Integer.is_even/1) |>
  Stream.take(10) |>
  Enum.to_list()
# [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20]

You could also use an Enum function as the last call to get a list out, and skip the separate Enum.to_list/1 call.
That makes your proposed helper function very simple as well
def first_matches(list, n, pred) do
  list |> Stream.filter(pred) |> Enum.take(n)
end



I think your recursive answer is pretty good!
David Maze's list |> Stream.filter(pred) |> Enum.take(n) is the simplest way, but using Stream can come with overhead (for small lists, plain old Enum.filter can even be faster!), so going with recursion to get the short-circuit behaviour is also a valid option.
The only thing I would change is to get the first item of the list in the function header via pattern matching, rather than using Kernel.hd and Kernel.tl (by the way, Kernel is implicit, you can simply write hd and tl).
def first_n([], _n, _pred), do: []
def first_n(_list, 0, _pred), do: []

def first_n([item | rest], n, pred) do
  if pred.(item) do
    [item | first_n(rest, n - 1, pred)]
  else
    first_n(rest, n, pred)
  end
end


Here's a benchmark for 10,000 items, taking 10, checking for even:
Comparison:
recursive            5.18 M
stream_filter        2.32 M - 2.23x slower +238.46 ns
enum_filter          1.24 M - 4.18x slower +613.82 ns

And for curiosity to see a case where Enum.filter is faster, 10 items taking 3:
Comparison:
recursive           15.10 M
enum_filter          8.74 M - 1.73x slower +48.15 ns
stream_filter        3.75 M - 4.03x slower +200.52 ns

Operating System: macOS
CPU Information: Apple M1 Pro
Number of Available Cores: 10
Available memory: 16 GB
Elixir 1.16.1
Erlang 26.1.2


That's a very instructive approach. I see that I'm still not used to regularily think of function calls as pattern matching.....

This answer could have been a reference to for/1 comprehension if take: non_neg_integer() option has been prioritized. Meanwhile, I could recommend my lazy_for library which accepts :take keyword argument since day 1.
Mix.install([:lazy_for])
import LazyFor

stream i <- 1..10, rem(i, 2) != 0, take: 5, do: i
#⇒ [1, 3, 5, 7, 9] 


This looks neat - a lazy comprehension! Do you happen to know, why this isn't included in the Elixir standard library? Is there any hidden trap or drawback in LazyFor we need to be careful to avoid?

Yes. LazyFor is limited to 42 clauses (that is not a joke, check the code.) But this number is configurable.
